# Draw a PolylineConnection between existing Nodes on a FigureCanvas

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, draw2d

I am having list of nodes to be drawn.Here Node means `RectangleFigure`. So, all these nodes are plotted first on canvas(`FigureCanvas`)
Then I have a map maintained having dependency relations between nodes drawn earlier.
In the map, keys are the nodes and values are nothing but a list of nodes maintained.

e.g.  There are 3 nodes, [ClassA, ClassB, InterfaceC]

I have them drawn on a canvas.
And my map is like below:
[ClassA=[ClassB], ClassB=[InterfaceC]]
So, it means `ClassA extends ClassB` and `ClassB implements InterfaceC`.

Now, I want to draw `PolylineConnection` in between the nodes drawn already ,using the map maintained.
So, how can I proceed for this?

Any pointers are really appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried ways to solve the problem, and it worked. So, adding answer for the own question.

Steps are as below:-
1. Consider the example in the question itself.
 There are 3 nodes, [ClassA, ClassB, InterfaceC]
and we have a map of relations in these nodes as
 [ClassA=[ClassB], ClassB=[InterfaceC]]
means `ClassA extends ClassB` and 
     `ClassB implements InterfaceC`.

1. Take one key at a time from the map, and fetch that node as a source of `PolylineConnection`.
2. Then for the same source(key in map) fetch node for values one-by-one as target node.
3. Now as we have both the source node and target node, we can draw connection in between using `Anchors`

The logic for fetching node is as below:-

1. Get all the children drawn on the canvas in one List, if the children is of type `RectangleFigure`(node) then comparing the label given to it we can fetch the node required.

Code snippet for more clarification

```
private RectangleFigure fetchNode(String node_label) {
        RectangleFigure emptyNode = new RectangleFigure();
        // get the list of nodes drawn on canvas
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List childrens = panel.getChildren();  //private IFigure panel;

        for (int count = 0; count < childrens.size(); count++) {
            if (childrens.get(count) instanceof RectangleFigure) {
                RectangleFigure node = (RectangleFigure) childrens.get(count);
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                List node_children = node.getChildren();
                for (int count2 = 0; count2 < node_children.size(); count2++) {
                    if (node_children.get(count2) instanceof Label) {
                        Label lbl = (Label) node_children.get(count2);
                        if (lbl.getText().equals(node_label)) {
                            return node;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return emptyNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples as part of the draw2d project. Check the details here: http://nyssen.blogspot.de/2010/12/draw2d-examples-hidden-treasure.html

Comment: I didnot find anything useful and related with PolylineConnection on the link suggested :|

Comment: Did you download the examples project and investigate it?

Comment: I know the basics about drawing Connections, the same examples are there on above blog. But the question asked above is somewhat tricky. I am stuck at that point. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.